# VBScript, how to I find an owner of a given process?

Tags: process, vbscript, wmi

I am trying to write vbs to find owner of process. Can you please help me?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176712.aspx this describes it and is directly from Microsoft's text about Scripting. You should ideally use PowerShell!

Answer (score 7):

My [google-fu](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=process%20owner%20wmi&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) is strong

[Microsoft Windows 2000 Scripting Guide - Determining Process Owners](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176712.aspx)

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
 ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process")
For Each objProcess in colProcessList
 colProperties = objProcess.GetOwner(strNameOfUser,strUserDomain)
 Wscript.Echo "Process " & objProcess.Name & " is owned by " _
 & strUserDomain & "\" & strNameOfUser & "."
Next
```